# The server tag is not well formed for repeater C#

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton, asprepeater

I try to open popup from linkbutton inside repeater. Here is my code:

```
<asp:Linkbutton cssclass="blue-button" id="LinkbtnPrint" runat="server" CommandName="PrintItem" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="javascript:dnnModal.show('<%# DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL("RptAppendixI","doanhnghiepid",Request.QueryString["doanhnghiepid"],"NamBC",NamBC2.ToString(),"ThangBC",ThangBC2.ToString(),"mid",Moduleid.ToString())+"?popUp=true" %>',false,580,950,false)">
                            <i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </asp:Linkbutton>
```

I get the error message: "System.Web.HttpParseException: The server tag is not well formed.".
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you're mixing two different technologies, if you're using javascript to handle the request and the way you can avoid the exception is by removing the runat="server" attribute. After that you can handle the command that you're defining in the linkbutton  in ajax call to the method from javascript, also there is this. I am not sure what are you trying to do while opening the modal but you can simplify it by creating a function inside the javascript that would handle those values instead of passing them straight away from the click event calling both js framework and dotnet framework at the same time.

`OnClick="javascript:dnnModal.show('<%# DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL("RptAppendixI","doanhnghiepid",Request.QueryString["doanhnghiepid"],"NamBC",NamBC2.ToString(),"ThangBC",ThangBC2.ToString(),"mid",Moduleid.ToString())+"?popUp=true" %>',false,580,950,false)`

if this doesn't help you could try to remove code above and do ajax call to navigate the url that you're calling on click.

Comment: Finally I solved it, by using another method. But I can understand what's wrong. Thank for your help.